# Is it possible to describe extension of places of a function field in MAGMA?

Tags: field-theory, math-software, computer-algebra-systems, function-fields, magma-cas

I would like to describe, for example, the unramified places of an extension $F'/F$ of function field (in one variable) in MAGMA calculator.
More specifically, given $F'/F$ an extension of function fields over the same constant field and given a place $P \in \mathbb{P}(F)$ of degree one, is it possible to describe the places $P_1',..., P_r' \in \mathbb{P}(F')$ such that $P_i' \mid P$ in MAGMA?

I can to do it in an impractical way, which is looking at the places of degree one over $F'$, using "Places(F', 1);", for me to describe it as "Places(F',1)[*some number*];". But this is impractical because I need to counting all places in the list of Places(F',1).

Is there a more practical way to do this?